# How to import class in package to another package?

Tags: java, class, package

ex:I want to define  a class A in a package called ABC and import the class A in the package ABC to another package which has a class X?

Comment: `import ABC.A;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare at the top of your class:

```
import ABC.A
```

and you can now use the public methods and attributes of class A

Answer (score 1):

I have not touched java in a while and I am not too familiar with it.
Since no one else has commented yet, here is my 2 cents

In python importing from another class...
you declare:

`{filename}.{classname}.{thenthemoduleyouwanttouse()}`

I would assume the same concept in java. Find a way to use object oriented programming.